# Trying To Output A String From An Object Passed Into A Set

Tags: java

I'm trying to output a string from an Object that has been passed into a set. The Following line is where my problem lies. It outputs [alex, jane] but with correct formatting I believe it should be outputted at alex jane. i.e. without the comma separated value and the brackets from the array.

```
System.out.print(module.getStudents() + " ");
```

I've tried various solutions including:

```
System.out.prinf(%s, module.getStudents() + " ");
```

and

```
System.out.prinln(module.getStudents().[whatever Netbeans makes available] + " ");
```

To help you better understand the problem. The idea of the application so far is to allow a user to search for a mosule ans return all students connected to it. The full source code bar the driver is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Control {

public void run() {

    Student jane = new Student("jane");
    Student alex = new Student("alex");

    Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();
    students.add(jane);
    students.add(alex);

    Module ufce1 = new Module("UFCE1");
    Module ufce2 = new Module("UFCE2");

    Set<Module> modules = new HashSet<Module>();
    modules.add(ufce1);
    modules.add(ufce2);

    jane.addModule(ufce1);
    jane.addModule(ufce2);
    alex.addModule(ufce2);

    ufce1.addStudent(jane);
    ufce2.addStudent(jane);
    ufce2.addStudent(alex);

    System.out.println("Search module code: ");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);        

    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String searchModule = scan.nextLine().trim();

    for (Module module : modules) {
        if (searchModule.equalsIgnoreCase(module.getName())) {

            Iterator it = students.iterator();
            Student student = (Student) it.next();
            if (student.getModules().contains(module)) {
                System.out.print(student + " ");
            }
        }
    }


}
}
```

Module Class:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Module {
private String name;
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();

public Module(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void addStudent(Student student){
      students.add(student);
}

public Set<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name; 
}

}
```

Student Class:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Student {
private String name;
  private Set<Module> modules = new HashSet<Module>();


public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void addModule(Module module){
      modules.add(module);
}

public Set<Module> getModules() {
    return modules;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this `System.out.print(module.getStudents() + " ");` you're implicitly calling the toString method on the HashSet instance. So to get the formatting you want, you have 2 choices:

1. iterate over the set and print it the way you want
2. Subclass HashSet and override toString to display the way you want it.

Comment: I've added an iterator into the code.  Is that what you were suggesting.  This prints out all students regardless of whether they are on that module or not

Comment: Yes because you don't do any filtering. What you'd need to do is:  `Student student = it.next();  if(student.getModules().contains(module)){ System.out.print(student+" ");}`

Comment: @ Chris Thanks.  But when I add this before: Iterator it = students.iterator(); it says incompatible types?

Comment: The code in my comment needs to go after `Iterator it= students.iterator();`  You can get rid of the incompatible types error by type casting:   `Student student = (Student)it.next();`

Comment: @ Chris Think I'm nearly there.  I have added it before your code and had to cast it like you said for it to compile but it only seems to print out a single element when it should print out two since both jane and alex are attached to ufce2.  I have added these changes to the original code as seen above.

Comment: You need to loop while the students iterator still contains values:  `Iterator it = students.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
  Student student = (Student) it.next();
  if (student.getModules().contains(module)) {
      System.out.print(student + " ");
  }
}`

Comment: @ Chris  Perfect.  Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getStudents` returns a `Set` object (a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), to be specific). `HashSet`, in turn, inherits a `toString()` method from [`AbstractCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) which behaves as follows:

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object).

You'll need to write your own method for converting a set of students into the format you want, or else you can doctor up the value returned by the default `toString` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The brackets and the commas are coming from the `toString()` call on the Set. If you look in the source code of this method, you will see that it adds those. You can override the `toString()` method of the Set in your Module class, or just not printing the Set directly but manually looping over all elements and printing them one by one

Answer (score 0):

@Chris gave an excellent solution in resolving your issues. There is however another one that I see more easy to implement and it is the following:

```
public String formatOutputString(){
    String setStrings = module.getStudents();
    // Get rid of opening bracket
    String formatedString = setStrings.replace("[", "");
    // Get rid of closing bracket
    formatedString = setStrings.replace("]", "");
    // Replace commas by spaces
    formatedString = setStrings.replace(",", " ");
    return formatedString;
}
```